# Origen Pin model has a supply attribute but no underlying Supply model?

Tags: origen-sdk

I can see that the Origen pin model has a '[supply](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/api/Origen/Pins/Pin.html#supply-instance_method)' method but I don't see an underlying Supply class.  Is this supply method really just used for grouping/iterating purposes?  Has anyone used for automating ATE levels creation?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Origen now supports [power domains](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/power/), which some people refer to power supplies.